# Search for certain files with specific condition and copy all files in another folder python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this;

```
id      record_id    Type
2001     1           A
2002     2           B
2002     3           B
2004     4           A
2004     5           A
2005     6           C
2006     7           A
2007     8           A
```

The above data is in the data frame.

I have folders like this:

```
E:/Files/Data/2001/1/1.jpg
E:/Files/Data/2002/2/1.jpg
E:/Files/Data/2002/3/2.jpg
E:/Files/Data/2004/4/1.jpg
E:/Files/Data/2004/5/2.jpg
E:/Files/Data/2005/6/1.jpg
E:/Files/Data/2006/7/1.jpg
```

Now what I want is:

I want to put all images of type A in one folder.

now I have a record_id on hand, and I have folder with that specific record_id named as subfolder(../1/1.jpg) so how can I copy all the image of type A in one folder , type B in another folder and so on.

The extension of each file should be like this:

for A type:

.../A/A_id(i.e /A/A_2001.jpg,../A/A_2004.jpg)

for B type:

.../B/B_id(i.e. ../B/B_2002.jpg,../B/B_2002_1.jpg)

How do I do it in python ?

This is what I tried so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
rootdir = 'E:Files/user_data'
output_path="E:/Files/Test_Folder/"
subdir1=[]
path=[]
for dirpath,subdir,filename in sorted(os.walk(rootdir)):
    subdir1.append(subdir)
    path.append(dirpath)

L=filter(None,subdir1)
del L[0]
Record_ids=[r_id for ids in L for r_id in ids]
User_records=pd.read_csv("User_records.csv")
records_data=User_records[["id",'recordId','recordType']]
A=records_data[records_data['recordType']=='A']

cnt=0
for dirpath,subdir,files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for ids in A['recordId']:
        for file in files:
            for r_id in Record_ids:
                if ids==r_id:
                    os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath,file),output_path+'A_'+str(cnt)+'.jpg')
                    cnt=cnt+1
```

Comment: Show us please what you have tried actually. You only explained us your idea how it should work.

Comment: And for type C ?

Comment: @ glegoux same for type C.

Comment: What is the id for type C ?

Comment: @ glegoux id for type C is 2005

Answer (score 0):

**file.csv**:

```
id,record_id,Type
2001,1,A
2002,2,B
2002,3,B
2004,4,A
2004,5,A
2005,6,C
2006,7,A
2007,8,A
```

Do:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

import pandas as pd

rootdir = 'E:Files/user_data'
output_path = 'E:/Files/Test_Folder/'


def path_source_img(_id, record_id):
    global rootdir
    return os.path.join(rootdir, str(_id), '{}.jpg'.format(record_id))


def path_dest_img(_type, _id, record_id):
    global output_path
    return os.path.join(output_path, _type,
                        '{}_{}_{}.jpg'.format(_type, _id, record_id))


df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path))

for _type in df['Type'].unique():
    imgs = df[df['Type'] == _type]
    for index, img in imgs.iterrows():
        from_img = path_source_img(img['id'], img['record_id'])
        to_img = path_dest_img(_type, img['id'], img['record_id'])
        print(from_img, '->', to_img)
        if not os.path.exists(output_path):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(to_img))
        copyfile(from_img, to_img)
```

Comment: The Image file name and record_id is different , I think you are assuming it same , but they are different

Comment: What is the source image file name ? How can I know that ?

Comment: There is one more columns for Image name (checksum list ) in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar and carried out few modification based on my requirement.

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
import pandas as pd

rootdir = 'Mention the root directory here'
output_path = 'Mention the output path'
df = pd.read_csv('mention the path to the csv file')
```

If the name of the image is in number format then use this

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype('str') 


def path_source_img(_id, record_id):
    global rootdir
    return os.path.join(rootdir, str(_id), '{}.jpg'.format(record_id))

def path_dest_img(_type, _id, record_id):
    global output_path
    return os.path.join(output_path, _type,
                        '{}.jpg'.format(record_id))
```

function def ensure_dir will create folder if required, if folder in the destination path is not available

```
def ensure_dir(file_path):
    directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

for _type in df['Type'].unique():
imgs = df[df['Type'] == _type]
for index, img in imgs.iterrows():
    from_img = path_source_img(img['id'], img['record_id'])
    to_img = path_dest_img(_type, img['id'], img['record_id'])
    from_img = '/'.join(from_img.split('\\'))
    to_img = '/'.join(to_img.split('\\'))
    print(from_img, '->', to_img)
    ensure_dir(to_img)
    copyfile(from_img, to_img)
```