# how to copy specific files from a folder based on the data in a column of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, file, filter, pattern-matching

I have a folder which contains a collections of files. I want to copy a subsets of those files to another folder. I need to filter my files based on two columns of a data frame.

so, my data frame has `CN` and `date` column, and the pattern in my file name is like this:

```
09060083_1542296310_2_CON_ENT-Floor-Practice_2015-09-25-false_MRB3738.txt
```

in which the first `9 charachter` is my `CN` column in data frame, here `09060083`. and the date in this filename is `date` in my data frame `2015-09-25`.

with these explanations how can I copy only the files which there is in my data frame?

till now I have done like this: `dffinal` is my data frame.

```
source_path = 'path to source folder'
files = os.listdir(source_path)
out_path ='destination path to copy the filtered files there'

files2 = [f for f in files if (re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', f)==dffinal['date']) & (f.rfind[1:8]==dffinal['CN'])]
copyfile(files2,out_path)
```

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756914/search-for-certain-files-with-specific-condition-and-copy-all-files-in-another-f) did not help me as it only matches some patterns in the file name not finally finding them in the data frame.

**Update** I felt like its an easy question and I do not know how to resolve it though no success yet :|
when I only consider the first condition to check what is wrong with that:

```
files2 = [f for f in files if ((re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}',f).group(0))==(dffinal['date']))]
```

raises error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Thanks :)

Comment: `re.match` returns a MatchObject and not the string matched. You need to capture the date string and use the MatchObject to compare it with the date.

Comment: why no idea anybody have:(